# Integral: $\aleph(f) = \int_0^1 (f(x^k) + f(x^{\frac{1}{k}})) f'(x) \; \mathrm{d}x$ is not dependent on $k$

Tags: calculus, integration

A few friends and I were investigating the integral $\aleph(f) = \displaystyle \int_0^1 \left ( f \left ( x^k \right ) + f \left ( x^{\frac{1}{k}} \right ) \right ) f'(x) \; \mathrm{d}x$ for specific functions $f$ that are integrable in the domain $[0, 1]$, given $k \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$.

An interesting property emerged: the integral did not seem dependent on $k$ for many functions we plugged in. For example, if $f(x) = \tan^{-1}(x)$, then $\aleph(f)$ would evaluate to $\frac{\pi^2}{16}$, if $f(x) = x^2 + 1$, then $\aleph(f)$ would evaluate to $3$, and $f(x) = e^x$ gave $\aleph(f) = e^2 - 1$. In fact, we observed that for any function $f \in \langle \{x^r \mid r \in \mathbb{R}^{+}_0\} \rangle$, $\aleph(f)$ seems to be independent of $k$, though these results are mostly without proof.

The obvious question arises — for which functions $f$ does $\aleph(f)$ give a value not dependent on $k$?

Unfortunately, we don't have much of an idea on how to tackle this question, but my suspicion is it may relate to the existence of the Fourier series of such functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Substitute $y=x^{1/k}$ in the second integral and then integrate by parts:
$$
\int_0^1 f(x^{1/k}) f'(x) \, dx = \int_0^1 f(y) f'(y^k) k y^{k-1} \, dy
= \bigl[ f(y) f(y^k)\bigr]_{y=0}^{y=1} - \int_0^1 f'(y) f(y^k) \, dy 
$$
so that
$$
\int_0^1 \bigl(f(x^k) + f(x^{1/k}) \bigr) f'(x) \, dx = f(1)^2 - f(0)^2 
$$
holds for all (continuously differentiable) functions $f$.

In the same manner one can show that 
$$
\int_0^1 \bigl(f(\phi(x)) + f(\phi^{-1}(x)) \bigr) f'(x) \, dx = f(1)^2 - f(0)^2 
$$
for an increasing differentiable mapping $\phi$ from the interval $[0, 1]$ onto itself.

Comment: Wonder what other inverse pairs this works for.

Comment: @martycohen: Apparently one can replace $\phi(y) = y^k$ by any (sufficiently smooth) injective mapping $\phi$ from $[0, 1]$ to $[0, 1]$.

Comment: Not at all surprised.